# How to upgrade Rails app from 2.3.5 to 3.2.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-2

I have Rails 2.3.5 app, I want to upgrade to 3.2.x. How do I upgrade to Rails 3.2.x?

Thanks

Comment: Have you watched these Railscasts? http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1 There's more to this than a simple upgrade, your code may break. Rails 3 introduces bundler, asset pipeline etc.

Comment: You might also take a look at this recent guide: http://railsapps.github.com/updating-rails.html

Answer (score 6):

I definitely recommend installing the Rails upgrade gem ([rails upgrade gem](https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade)). It's proven for me to be incredibly useful as a starting point for listing and verifying all the required upgrades to get to Rails 3.0.

I would also recommend this ebook http://www.railsupgradehandbook.com/

Once you're at Rails 3.0, you'll need to migrate to the asset pipeline, this is another good starting point: http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1

This won't be a simple task and you'll need to ensure that your code doesn't break at each step, but these are tools I've found were great to get the ball rolling.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the link, http://www.spritle.com/blogs/2013/02/08/upgrade-rails-2-application-to-rails-3/ 
It may helpful to you.